# How to auto adjust site to appear the same in every window, including mobile

Tags: wordpress

This code automatically adjusts the page height successfully:

```
#primary {
height: 400px;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not display the page same for everyone if they have different screen resolutions. I need something that will display the site the same regardless of screen resolution, and display it the same on mobile (not a mobile site, but the same sit on mobile, without scrolling. That's what they want.)

I have seen this done on a Joomla site, but can it be done in WordPress?

Thank you very much - I really appreciate your help.

Comment: This is a CSS question. Your CSS in question, is setting the container div of the ID, primary, to the height of 400px. If you set the height to 100%, it should fill it's parent container. If you're looking for more information on how CSS works, Chris Coyier has some excellent stuff on his site http://css-tricks.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up with, fixing the menu at the bottom and having the text scroll above it. The height is 57 to allow my menu buttons to show on mobile.

```
body {
      overflow: scroll;
}

#colophon {
      background: white;
      bottom: 0;
      font-size: 13px;
      height: 57px;
      position: fixed;
      padding: 0 30px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
}

.entry-content {
      padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```